# Determining a bounding polygon surrounding specific points

Tags: geometry, polygon, points

I've been trying to figure out how to determine a bounding polygon around a specific set of points (set A) from another set of points (set B) such that the polygon only contains points in set A. For simplicity, we can assume the polygon will be convex, set A will only include 2 points, and a solution will exist from the given data.

For example, given:
[these points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehFI2.jpg), I want to create a polygon around the blue points from the red points like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvHHc.jpg). This could be done by finding the next point with the greatest angle while not cutting through the blue points, but I don't want the result to be too minimal like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPeRN.jpg).

Any suggestions or algorithms for solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if you calculate triangulation over all (red and blue) points, then triangles containing blue vertices, form the first approximation of needed region. This approximation usually would be concave, so one need to  cut off "ears".

If result looks too small, it is possible to add the third vertices of outer border triangles if they don't violate convexity.